# OSMGeoAdmin: Imported OSM maps: points, lines and roads are ok, not multipolygons

Tags: django, postgis

- Download an OSM map from [geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/).
- Import it with `osm2pgsql` (basic commands, no fancy stuff)

You will have your tables ready to use.

Here's are my models (all the same fields for `Line`, `Polygon`, `Point` and `Roads`, just one is enough):

```
class PlanetOsmLine(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'planet_osm_line'
        managed = False

    osm_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    # ...tons of other field (unused)...
    way = GeometryField(default=None)
```

Now, to display it in the admin interface, basic `admin.ModelAdmin` does the job and it work, like this for a road:

[image: basic admin display]

Let's add the `OSMGeoAdmin` interface with this code:

```
class PlanetOsmAdmin(OSMGeoAdmin):
    pass

my_admin_site.register(PlanetOsmLine, PlanetOsmAdmin)
my_admin_site.register(PlanetOsmPolygon, PlanetOsmAdmin)
my_admin_site.register(PlanetOsmPoint, PlanetOsmAdmin)
my_admin_site.register(PlanetOsmRoads, PlanetOsmAdmin)
```

You'll get this, which is *way* nicer:

[image: osmgeoadmin admin display]

OSM Admin works with everything except polygons. Here's the basic view:

[image: polygons basic admin interface]

And when I do `my_admin_site.register(PlanetOsmPolygon, PlanetOsmAdmin)` then I get **only** this, always the same place:

[image: problematic polygons OSM admin interface]

If the polygons are displayed properly *without* `OSMGeoAdmin`, and are not displayed properly *with* it. There's no error in the console log of Chrome.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. You can override some values in `OSMGeoAdmin`, and  setting `display_wkt` to `True` showed me it was empty.

```
class PlanetOsmAdmin(OSMGeoAdmin):
    display_wkt = True
```

So I did a step-by-step debugging and found out that my value for polygons are:

```
SRID=3857;POLYGON ((5024019.9 -1441890.9, ..., 5024019.9 -1441890.690534543))
```

In the source code (`/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/admin/widgets.py`) they ignore the value if it's not of the same expected type (or if it's not `GEOMETRY`):

[image: value ignored because it's not GEOMETRY]

So I've commented those 3 lines and now it works.

The working solution I've implemented is:

```
if (value and value.geom_type.upper() != self.geom_type and
        self.geom_type != 'GEOMETRY' and
        (self.geom_type == 'MULTIPOLYGON' and
         'POLYGON' not in value.geom_type.upper())):
    value = None
```